# How to customise the min/max range of a Google bar chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Say I have a chart like this:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKgI0.png

I'd like the label for max x-axis value (currently 150) to always read 120 (the actual bar value will never exceed this)

I've tried a few different configuration options and unable to achieve what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following to the chart options...

```
hAxis: {
  viewWindow: {
    max: 120
  }
}
```

**fyi:**

this option *is not* available for use with *material* charts...

`google.charts.Bar`

with

`packages: ['bar']`

---

**as an alternative** to *material*, you can use *core* chart...

`google.visualization.BarChart`

with

`packages: ['corechart']`

with the following option...

`theme: 'material'`

Comment: hope this helps -- if using _material_, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)